# Document input and return values in functions: python

Tags: python

I have the following function with the following documentation:

```
def plate_detect(img,cascade_classifier):
    """
    :param img: src image
    :param cascade_classifier: var under cv2.CascadeClassifier
    :return: tuple[0] = img with rectangle over the features
    :return: tuple[1] tuple[2]= top left, bottom right coordinate
    :return: tuple[3] tuple[4]= width height
    """
    img_copy = np.copy(img)
    plate_cascade = cascade_classifier

    parameters = plate_cascade.detectMultiScale(img_copy, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5)  #
    # receive x,y ,width, high
    for (x, y, width, height) in parameters:
        cv2.rectangle(img_copy, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (255), 5)
    return img_copy, parameters[0,0], parameters[0,1],parameters[0,2],parameters[0,3]
```

Would like the output documentation to be better then this:

```
def plate_detect(img:any, cascade_classifier:any) -> tuple[any,any,any,any,any]
```

Does python allowing better documentation for input and return values instead of "any"?

Comment: What exactly are you using to generate the documentation?

Comment: If supported: Have you tried with *type hinting*? for instance: `def f(arg : int) -> (int, int)`. At least this works with `pydoc`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  - pycharm hints, not sure what other IDE suggests